# neo4j.Asp.Net.Identity Sample Project

Tags: neo4j, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2, neo4jclient

I'm new at neo4j and I want to use neo4j.Asp.Net.Identity for authentication and authorization but I can't find any sample that implements that.Anybody knows how can I find a sample for that? 
I'm also want to use Token-Base authentication for authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 1):

The project is here: https://github.com/assimoes/Neo4j.AspNet.Identity the problem you'll have is that it doesn't implement the third-party authentication - i.e. you can't just drop it in and it'll work with something like MVC's Facebook/Twitter stuff.

Your best bet is to get the code from GitHub and reference the project directly as you're going to have to implement some new interfaces, and personally - I would change the implementation of the data structure - roles, authentication tokens don't work (if I remember correctly) - so you'd probably need to fix them.

You might actually be better off using *my* fork: https://github.com/cskardon/Neo4j.AspNet.Identity which I've been playing around with for a while in an MVC5 project and it's working so far (I'll create a demo version of the MVC5 soonish).

Comment: I can attest to the awesomness of his fork. I downloaded the nuget packages, followed the instructions on the github page, and it all basically worked out of the box, after I also had to update Newtonsoft.Json. I had login via facebook working before with MS SQL as backend, and now it just works with Neo4j. (Visual Studio 2015, .NET 4.7)

Answer (score 0):

There is now a NuGet package for it. Click on the link in the Nuget documentation, and it should take you to the appropriate web-site.